# I used the wrong channel for my Nexus 4; How do I upgrade it, and what channel do I use?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, phone, nexus-4, adb

I used the wrong channel for my Nexus 4; How do I upgrade it, and what channel do I use?

## Backstory:

- Followed this tutorial:
  https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/image-channels/
- Have Nexus 4, so I chose the following option:

  `Nexus 4`  | `Track the latest development`    | `ubuntu-touch/devel/ubuntu`
- `ubuntu-touch/devel/ubuntu` turned out to be a very old image.
- Popey advised to use `ubuntu-touch/rc/bq-aquaris.en` for Nexus 4
- Trying to upgrade, ran into a few problems.

### Questions

- Do I have to completely reflash my phone?
- Do I run the commands from phone, or computer?
- What commands do I use?
- What do the following errors mean?

-

```
`2015/10/04 09:01:21 Start pushing /home/akiva/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu-touch/rc/bq-aquaris.en/mako/version-25.tar.xz to device`

`2015/10/04 09:01:21 error pushing:`
```

and

```
`2015/10/04 08:48:24 Expecting the device to expose an adb interface...`

`device cannot be detected over adb`
```

Comment: Questions on AskUbuntu should be one question with one answer. Not multiple questions with multiple answers.

Comment: @dobey I believe this is meant to be a wiki entry.

Comment: This is just the questions I asked tertiary to trying to reflash my phone. It's meant to help people who made the same mistakes I did here, and to find this page as a solution. Also; I hate formatting wikis.

Answer (score 3):

## Solution

- Do I have to completely reflash my phone?

No. Once you have ubuntu on there, you can simply update.

---

- Do I run the commands from phone, or computer?

Computer, with phone plugged in.

---

- What command do I use?

Boot up phone up normally, and run this command from your computer:

`adb reboot recovery`

Wait until the phone gets into recovery mode, and run this command:

`ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/rc/bq-aquaris.en`

---

## Possible Errors

```
$ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/rc/bq-aquaris.en
2015/10/04 09:01:21 Start pushing /home/akiva/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu-touch/rc/bq-aquaris.en/mako/version-25.tar.xz to device
2015/10/04 09:01:21 error pushing:
```

This is because you are logged into the phone. You need to log into recovery mode with the command: `adb reboot recovery`

```
$ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/rc/bq-aquaris.en 
2015/10/04 08:48:24 Expecting the device to expose an adb interface...
device cannot be detected over adb
```

You are probably in the Bootloader instead of recovery mode. You won't be able to connect to adb there. If not this, you could also try the command:

`adb wait-for-device`

and try plugging it in until it is noticed.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone can boot into Ubuntu, just enter the developer mode by selecting 'settings>About>Developer Mode' and then connect your device to your PC and run 'ubuntu-device-flash' as described by Akiva.

If you get errors try running 'ubuntu-device-flash --clear-cache touch'.

Or check if your device is really connected with 'adb devices'. This should list all connected devices. with

--
I have just now no PC here, so all commands are just written by mind. Gonna check this tomorrow, soon.