# Upgrade bq Aquaris M10 from 15.04 to 16.04?

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-touch, bq

I have recently purchased the Aquaris m10 FHD, and want to upgrade to 16.04.
How do I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure you can directly update from 15.04 to 16.04. At least for the desktop version(s) of Ubuntu skipping releases during an upgrade is unsupported (unless going from one LTS release to the next).

Answer (score 1):

Update:

I was wrong below. My system is still 15.04 after ubuntu upgrade. Ubuntu 16.04 expected release date for touch (OTA-11) is currently 1 May 2016: 
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-calendar-app/+milestone/0.6

Some time after that I expect we'll be given the option to upgrade.

To check your current version enter `lsb_release -a` into the terminal

---

original answer not correct because not yet available:

> - Go to System Settings by dragging down on the top right menu icons to > reveal the mini panel, select the System icon and then tap System Settings
> - Tap on Updates
> - Tap the option to install updates (I forget the wording as currently - I have no updates to install)
> - Specifically click on the ubuntu update option as you will be asked to confirm to restart the system to install the ubuntu (make sure you are plugged into a power supply for this)
> - the tablet will restart and you will see a spinning ubuntu logo on a black background. This takes many minutes to complete and eventually takes you back to the login screen
>
> After I upgraded ubuntu my location service stopped working. The location icon flashed on and off. To fix this I went into the location options and set that it should not use WIFI or GPS - i.e. turned of option fully off. I then went into the energy management settings and turned off the WIFI and GPS services. (I think what happened is that the update turned off GPS  at the firmware level but ubuntu thought it was still on). I then turned back on all of the options and pressed and held down the power button to bring up the option to restart. Once restarted the location option worked again and so did long touch for copy and paste.

Comment: Tried that...  No luck.  My system still says that it's on 15.04???  Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: I would be very surprised if that worked, given that Ubuntu 16.04 hasn't been released for the M10 yet. The OTA-11 update will be out in a few weeks, and is expected to be based on 16.04, until then you're stuck with 15.04.

Comment: Thanks! I was starting to doubt my sanity trying to figure out why my tablet was on 15.04 and the over-the-air update didn't update it to 16.04. Didn't help that all of the marketing materials for the tablet show "16:04" prominently.

Answer (score 0):

You can change channels as described here:

[I used the wrong channel for my Nexus 4; How do I upgrade it, and what channel do I use?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/681500/i-used-the-wrong-channel-for-my-nexus-4-how-do-i-upgrade-it-and-what-channel-d)

As described, you need to connect to your computer via usb and run

```
adb reboot recovery
```

Then something like this

```
ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/rc/bq-aquaris.en
```

A list of available channels may be found here

https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/image-channels/

**Disclaimer**: I have not done tried this myself, and I have no idea what harm it may (or may not) cause to your device.

**Edit**: The appropriate channel for BQ M10 appears to be ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris-pd.en as listed here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/ReleaseNotes/OTA-10